# It seems that sometimes Delphi is case-sensitive - "override method should match case of ancestor"

Tags: delphi, compiler-construction, delphi-2006

Today I've encountered a 'strange' hint:

> override method xxxx should match case of ancestor yyyy.

Solution was to declare the method name exactly as in the ancestor....I believe this is something which rested in the compiler since the Delphi.Net compiler...

Declaring the method exactly as in the ancestor made the compiler 'silent'. There are other 'case-sensitive' hints/warnings in Delphi 2006 and up?

Comment: It is not really 'case-sensitive', it just says it is a good habit to use the same case.

Comment: One thing that has always been case sensitive in Delphi is the name of the `Register` procedure in designtime package. But there is no hint or warning if you get it wrong, you just don't get the expected result (component would not show up).

Comment: Maybe a comment `// please compile! (without hints!)` above this method declaration helps ;)

Comment: Imports of external functions are case-sensitive.

Comment: @mjn, you can enclose the part with a [disable hints-re-enable hints] block if i'm not mistaken. The uglyness of **that** hack makes me a bit sick though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a hint that's in place to protect your code when cooperating with 3rd party code.
This hint was introduced with the addition of Delphi for .net, because some other .net platforms are case-sensitive.

***Note that the hint does not imply any case sensitivety on Delphi's part.***
Only in point 1 below is Delphi itself case sensitive, point 2 is an artifact of the way the Delphi compiler calls the case-sensitive function `GetProcAddress()` in the Windows API.

**Case sensitive behavior in Delphi**

**1-Registering components**
I don't know of any other hints that are case sensitive, but note that when you write your own components and you want to register them, the register function that you declare **must** be written like so:

```
procedure Register;  <<-- Leading capital required.
```

If you don't Delphi will not add your new component.

**2-Importing external functions**

As stated by David, when importing external functions, the exact case used in the DLL must be preserved.

**Individual hints cannot be disabled**
Note that you cannot disable a specific hint: [Can specific Delphi hints be disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444443/can-specific-delphi-hints-be-disabled)

Comment: It's technically the Windows API function GetProcAddress which is case sensitive.